# Removing a CSS property/value from a bootstrap class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to remove the position "top: 0" from a bootstrap class of card-img-overlay. All other property/values are exactly what I need. How do I accomplish this?[image]

Comment: You override the CSS.

Comment: FYI, the [initial value for `top` is `auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top#Specifications).  Overriding it with `auto` is basically the same as "removing" it.

Comment: @JosephMarikle thanks. That was actually helpful and worked.

Comment: @J.G.Sable You're welcome.  Glad I could help. :)